# How to trigger 2nd @wire call after results of another @wire call

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to call out to a Apex class after my first @wire call get back with results. The apex class is a simple weather API call that needs the city from the Account object and I know those results exist in my return.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountRecord from '@salesforce/apex/LeadInfoLWCController.getAccountRecord';
import getWeather from '@salesforce/apex/IntakeWeatherController.getWeather';

export default class LeadInfoComponent extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  cityName = '';
  @wire(getAccountRecord, { recordId: '$recordId'})
  record;

get addressLine2() {
    let billingAddress = this.record.data[0].BillingAddress;
    let city = billingAddress.city;
    this.cityName = billingAddress.city;
    let state = billingAddress.state;
    let zipcode = billingAddress.postalCode;
    let address = '';


    if (city) {
        address+= city + ',';
    }
    if(state) {
        address+= ' ' + state;
    }

    if(zipcode) {
        address+= ' ' + zipcode;
    }
    return address;
}
@wire(getWeather, { city: '$this.cityName'})
weather;
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways of tracking the variable including just trying to pass

```
'$this.record.data[0].BillingAddress.city'
```

but that also doesn't fire. I have also tested the class by passing a hard coded string of a City name and can confirm the class functions as expected. I just don't see any info online that is clear what I am trying to do.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: you will have to do it [imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex), meaning, not using a decorated method

Comment: If you *really* want a wired method, extract the city from the record data and put it into a separate variable. I'm not sure you can do "deep tracking" for reactive parameters.